# How to play same music through computer speakers as well as network audio with Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-7, audio, itunes, windows-media-player, speakers

I want to be able to use Windows Media Player in the same manner as iTunes using the computer speakers as well as network attached speaker system. When I use the Play To feature this works fine but the track played on the computer is often different to the track played on the network speakers. How to I get these to sync? In other words play the same audio through Windows Media player on both the local speakers as well as the network speakers?
Thanks
Hope that makes sense by the way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this link what you are lookin for?

[Stream Music Over Your Home Network with Windows Media Player 12](http://www.7tutorials.com/stream-music-over-your-home-network-windows-media-player-12)